# How can I install an Apple Magic Trackpad on a PC without Boot Camp?

Tags: windows, drivers, magic-trackpad

I have a [Apple Magic Trackpad](http://www.apple.com/magictrackpad/) and I'd like to use it with my PC.  I have no other Apple hardware besides the Trackpad.  I do not have OSX and thus no Boot Camp CD.

The Trackpad uses Bluetooth and will pair with Windows 7 without specific drivers (appears as an HID-Compliant Mouse), but all it will do is point and left click (physical click, no touch tap).  With Apple's Windows driver update, I should be able to achieve:

- Tap to click
- Dragging
- Drag lock
- Secondary click
- Two-finger scrolling
- Two-finger secondary tap/click

But **how can I obtain this driver without Boot Camp installed**?  Apple's Boot Camp update EXE will not install on my PC (non-Apple hardware).

Comment: Did you get the above functions (tap to click, drag, drag lock, secondary click, two finger scroll, two finger secondary tap/click)?

Comment: @howiecamp yes, all the listed functions are available after installing the boot camp driver.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**DIY:** using 7-zip, you can extract the drivers from Apple update download.

1. Download the Boot Camp Software Update 3.2 For Windows: [32-bit](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1333) (280MB) or [64-bit](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL979) (121MB)
2. Open the EXE with 7-zip and extract (or navigate into) the BootCampUpdate .MSP file
3. In the "BootCamp3200aToBootCamp3200" folder, extract Binary.AppleWirelessTrackpad_Bin (another compressed file itself)
4. Decompress the contents of this _Bin file into a folder.  You should see AppleWTP files and DPInst.exe among others.
5. Run DPInst.exe and follow the dialogs.

*- or -* **Quick and dirty shortcut:**

1. Download and run a self-extracting archive produced from the DIY procedure: [32-bit](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=WZ91OL5B) (1.7MB) or [64-bit](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=11C4FVTC) (2.2MB) - driver version 3.1.0.7, 8/24/2010

**Notes:**

- This should work whether or not you are already paired, and will also update an older driver in-place (no need to uninstall first)
- To manually install the driver (without running DPInst.EXE), look for the "Bluetooth HID device" in Device Manager (it will show VID 000205ac and PID 030e in the Properties if you have the right one).
- The driver will not install onto the "HID-compliant mouse", only its parent device.

**See also:**
[How to modify Magic Trackpad settings (without Bootcamp control panel)](https://superuser.com/questions/172658)

Comment: The Quick and dirty shortcut links are not working

Comment: Is there any new download for Windows 10 installations? I figure a driver from 2010 is probably a bit aged.

Answer (score 2):

I will add that the latest revision to the bootcamp software, as of 12/1/2014, had self executing exe files for the devices and no longer requires you to do all this hard stuff.  Just download the bootcamp installer directly from apple (http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1721), use 7-zip to get inside and find the Apple Drivers in this path:  BootCamp > Drivers > Apple

Install away!

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [ExtraMagic](http://extramagic.forbootcamp.org/index.htm) (freeware) with success. It uses the bootcamp drivers under the hood afaik.

Just make sure you pair via bluetooth first (off -> on to enable pairing on the trackpad).

Answer (score 0):

Ask a friend who owns a mac to download bootcamp 32/64 (depending on what you need) and do the following to obtain windows drivers :

Control-click on the Boot Camp Assistant program, choose Show Package Contents, and then navigate into Contents » Resources. 
Inside there you'll find DiskImage.dmg. Just burn that disk image, and you'll have your Windows drivers CD.

Then in Windows install the driver by indicating the correct folder where the drivers you need are.